# How to add a data-bound item to the master page of a BIRT report?

Tags: birt

I have a BIRT report which uses scripted data sources. The report has one parameter which is the path to an XML file. The XML contains a representation of a Java object. The object is deserialised and made available to the report via the scripted data source.

The 'open' script:

```
importPackage(Packages.com.acme.atf.model.dao);
model = new Packages.com.acme.atf.model.dao.AtfObjects();

path = inputParams["ProtocolPath"];
try {
    var list = model.getProtocols(path);
    itr = list.iterator();
}catch(e){
    log(e);
}
```

The 'fetch' script:

```
try {
    if(itr.hasNext()){
        p = itr.next();
        row["ProtocolObject"] = p;
        row["ProductVersion"] = p.getProductVersion();
        row["ProductName_de"] = p.getProductName_de();
        row["ProductName_en"] = p.getProductName_en();
        // etc.
        return true;
    }
} catch(x) {
    log(x);
}
return false;
```

If I just use the DataSet in the body then I get a result. A report is created.

If I add a data-bound grid to the master page header in order to display the `ProductName` field then the report is not generated properly. If the data item in the master page is removed, the report is generated correctly.

It seems the master page is created first and this possibly prevents the data set in the body from being generated properly.

Am I making an error? Can I add data-bound items to the master page?

Comment: I am not sure what is causing your error, but you should be able to use JS to capture the data item you want in a report variable, then post the report variable in the master page.

Comment: @JamesJenkins - Thanks for the suggestion! Where should I perform that action? In the body area? I thought the master page gets processed first...

Comment: Did you test that log(...) actually works? And if it works, I would add log-Statements at the very beginning of the methods; just to verify that they are actually executed.

Comment: @paul I have not tried it, but I would think just creating the variables in the outline, should do it. I think the master page will be happy to go look for the value of the variable when the report is being created in your chosen format (i.e. PDF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually to do with the fact that, if you use a data set more than once, BIRT starts caching results and uses serialisation. The POJO I was using was not completely serializable (one of the enclosed classes) and therefore was null when deserialized. This caused the problem.

I actually got to the answer as a result of another question. See here [What might cause BIRT to lose an object reference between fetch and render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890653/what-might-cause-birt-to-lose-an-object-reference-between-fetch-and-render)

Comment: you can accept your own answer to show, that your question is solved.